# Input value in workbook 1 find it in workbook 2 and input a corresponding value into workbook 1

Tags: excel, vba

I’m very new to VBA, not really sure where to start. I have two separate workbooks saved in the same folder. What I am looking for is when column A is populated in workbook 1;

[image: worksheet 1]

I want a macro that searches for that number in workbook 2 column C. If a match is found then I want the corresponding value from column F in workbook 2 to be copied onto column I in workbook 1:

[image: workbook 2]

If a match is not found just leave the cell blank.

If more than one match is found, use the greatest number.
Sometimes workbook 1 has multiple pages as well.
Workbook 2 won't be opened by the user, they will just populate the data in workbook 1 and the macro runs automatically if data in column A changes.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please learn [ask].

Comment: Have look at this to start : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54447253/4961700

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need VBA here, but I'm brand new to VBA.  This is what I would use, and I'm sure someone can convert this to VBA.  For reference, I'm calling your workbooks Book1 & Book2.  In Book2 (the one you want the result in) use this formula:

**=IF(MAX(IF([Book1]Sheet1!$C$2:$C$20000=A26,[Book1]Sheet1!$F$2:$F$20000))=0,"",(MAX(IF([Book1]Sheet1!$ C$2:$C$20000=A26,[Book1]Sheet1!$F$2:$F$20000))))**

To make this an array formula, go back to the cell with your formula, hit F2 & then CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, and it will put brackets around your formula to make it look like this:

**{=IF(MAX(IF([Book1]Sheet1!$C$2:$C$20000=A26,[Book1]Sheet1!$F$2:$F$20000))=0,"",(MAX(IF([Book1]Sheet1!$ C$2:$C$20000=A26,[Book1]Sheet1!$F$2:$F$20000))))}**

You can then drag that formula down or fill down that formula.

Note:  $C$2:$C20000 & $F2:$F20000 is assuming that your part numbers & prices or whatever they are start on row 2, and there are less than 20000 rows, if it is more, just replace the 20000 to however high you need.  The A26, appears to my old eyes to be the first cell in which you are typing in the part numbers which correspond to Sheet1 column C.